# Arshaw full calendar does not show time properly

Tags: angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar

[image]I am using Arshaw full calendar[Angular bootstrap] in my project, but after implementing it, Whenever I go to the day view and click on the time span say **12.00am**, day click event gets fired and if I extract date from the view object I get the same date but the timing shows **05.30.0**, That means there is difference of 5.30 hours... Why is this happening, I am using the latest version of master calendar. I am sharing the snapshot of the same. Please help, Thank you..!!!

Comment: Please help guys..!!

Comment: This may be timezone problem or your date object creation problem , if you give the detail code, i can help you out.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I just added  timezone: 'local' to my config object and everything worked fine.. :)